# changes of output parameters in a callable named query in Hibernate 5

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

It seems that the format of a output parameter in a named query has been changed from a question mark notation (?) to some named variable, in Hibernate 4, the query config looked like:

```
<named-native-query name="getActiveBook"
    result-class="ActiveBookBody"
result-set-mapping="getActiveBookMap">
    <query>CALL pr_get_book_cache_refresh(?, :region, :businessDate)</query>
    <hint name="org.hibernate.callable" value="True"/>
</named-native-query>
```

the calling part looked like:

```
Query query = getNamedQueryFor(session, "getActiveBook");
query.setParameter("region", "AMER");
query.setParameter("businessDate", "2023-06-30");
query.list();
```

Since we migrated from Hibernate 4 to 5, it seems the ? notation was deprecated, and replaced with some arbitrary named variable. After consulting the web I came up recoding the config part like:

```
<named-native-query name="getActiveBook"
    result-class="ActiveBookBody"
    result-set-mapping="getActiveBookMap">
    <query>CALL pr_get_book_cache_refresh(out, :region, :businessDate)</query>
    <hint name="org.hibernate.callable" value="True"/>
</named-native-query>
<sql-result-set-mapping name="getActiveBookMap">
    <column-result name="out"/>
</sql-result-set-mapping>
```

and on the calling part, I added this:

```
query.setParameter("out", ParameterMode.OUT);
```

However I didn't get it work. Depending on how I tweaked the code, such as removing the additional line from calling part, adding/removing the colon (:), putting the "out" at the end of the parameter list, etc, the error varied with "**Invalid column index**" or "**mixed param strategy**" or "**wrong number of parameters**".

I couldn't find anything from Hibernate official documents either.

Can anyone kindly help? If it helps - I am using Java 11.